# Using a custom JavaScript object yields error with Firestore document: "Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's my first project, please can you ask me who is a problems.

So, in first I have this function that add data on firebase:

```
  addpost() {
    let newposts = new Posts(
      this.addForm.value
    )   
    this.postsservice.addPosts(newposts);
  }
```

In second: service.ts

```
  addPosts(posts: Posts){
        console.log(posts)
        this.postsCollection.add(posts);
    }
```

Model.ts

```
export class Posts {
    id?: string;
    title?: string;
    description?: string;
    upload?: string;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.title = obj && obj.title
        this.description = obj && obj.description,
        this.upload = obj && obj.upload
    }
    }
```

My [Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uDTv.png)

When I add data show this error:

> core.js:4352 ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set()
> called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom
> object (found in document posts/OLYLatFTZFr0zVuM3Q4S)
> at new n (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:151375:23)
> at Fs (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:165124:16)
> at t.s_ (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:164842:16)
> at Us (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:165077:37)
> at ks (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:164882:5)
> at n.set (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:166427:40)
> at n.add (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:166941:59)
> at AngularFirestoreCollection.add (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33999:25)
> at PostsService.addPosts (http://localhost:4200/main.js:498:30)
> at PostsComponent.addpost (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1014:27) defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:4352 handleError @ core.js:4400
> handleError @ core.js:8765 executeListenerWithErrorHandling @
> core.js:15217 wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @
> core.js:15249 schedulerFn @ core.js:24872
> __tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183 next @ Subscriber.js:122
> _next @ Subscriber.js:72 next @ Subscriber.js:49 next @ Subject.js:39 emit @ core.js:24841 onSubmit @ forms.js:5552
> FormGroupDirective_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.js:5605
> executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:15214
> wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15249 (anonymous)
> @ platform-browser.js:582 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:399
> onInvokeTask @ core.js:27474 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:398
> runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:167 invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:480
> invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1621 globalZoneAwareCallback @
> zone-evergreen.js:1647

Comment: What does your console log show?  Is it logging what you expect?  We can't see what `.addForm.value` is, so we don't really, know what exactly you're passing to Firestore.

Comment: newpost Posts {title: "tttt", description: "ddddd", upload: "uuuu"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, Firestore doesn't accept custom objects.  You should provide a plain JavaScript object.  You should generate something that's equivalent to this in the end:

```
this.postsCollection.add({
  title: "tttt",
  description: "ddddd",
  upload: "uuuu"
});
```

It might be worthwhile to use an interface to describe this object rather than defining a class that you have to create with `new`.